# What is a terminal plane in high frequency circuits?

Tags: microwave, terminal

The term "terminal planes" come up very frequently in books on microwave circuits. What exactly does the term mean?

The closest answer I have got is

> A terminal plane, or reference plane, is the  equivalent of a terminal
>   pair in a low-frequency network
>   -Foundations of microwave engineering, Robert E Collins

But I don't understand what a "plane" is in this sense, and I don't understand why we couldn't just use the term terminal port?

Comment: @DKNguyen No, it doesn't

Comment: The reference plane is exactly that: The plane relative to which distances, and hence phases, etc are described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a reference plane because, for both coaxial cable and hollow rectangular waveguides, an ideal connector cuts across the guide in a plane cut.

This is what a waveguide connector looks like, a flange with a plane cut across the guide.

[image]

This is a pair of APC-7 (A Precision Connector - 7mm) connectors, designed for precision measurement specifically so that the breaks in the inner and the outer line up to form a plane.

[image]

Distances from the 'connector' are measured from this plane.

In a more conventional RF connector like BNC, N-type or SMA, the break in the outer defines the plane.

Any plane across the guide can be taken as a reference plane when doing maths with the phase of RF waves propagating along the guide.

The most usually used planes are those of the connectors, as we are usually interested in reflection coefficients of components with respect to their connectors.

You will however sometimes see evaluation boards for RF components, with a line drawn on the board across a microstrip line, with a note that some S-Parameters are quoted with reference to this plane. This can be useful when you will be copying the reference design, and can choose that cut point as your virtual connector.

Comment: So any cross-section of this waveguide could be my "reference plane" right?

Comment: @PradyothShandilya yes! That's up to you to define :) (attention: under the assumption that the wave is normal to that plane, but I was assuming that this was inherent when you said "cross-section")

Comment: Damn, the combined answers of both MarcusMüller and Neil_UK gives me the right answer. How do I select the correct answer?

Comment: @PradyothShandilya Mine has prettier pictures, but the advice is to wait for 24 hours before accepting any answer, as a better one might come in from a different time zone.

Comment: @Neil_UK, lmao. Good advice though. Any chance one of you guys can combine both the answers to a single one? Or is there an option for me to do that?

Comment: @PradyothShandilya no, why? I think you're right, the combination gives you the best overall idea, but these answers work as separate pieces of text – and I do agree with Neil, he's got the prettier pictures :) So, just accept what you slightly favor, neither of us will mind!

Answer (score 3):

The reference plane is exactly that: The plane relative to which distances, and hence phases, etc are described.

This often goes a bit beyond the strict meaning of the word "plane": it often also comes with an (usually very explicitly stated) understanding that a wave front "comes in" through that plane, and that the plane is at a given reference impedance \$Z_0\$. Think of it as a "cut" through the path a wave travels, especially in closed wave guides.

This becomes especially relevant with measurement equipment, where "phase obtained through a system" really has no meaning until you specify at which point you define your zero-phase to be.